# django updateview form related model

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

My **models.py** file is as

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    body = models.TextField()
    category = models.ManyToManyField("PostCategory", blank=True)

class PostImages(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="..")
    post = models.ForeignKey("Post", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="images")
```

and **forms.py**

```
class UpdateBlogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = "__all__"
        exclude = ("blogger", "view")
        widgets = {
            "language": forms.Select(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            "title": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            "body": forms.Textarea(attrs={"row": "25", "class": "form-control"}),
        }
```

I've an **updateview** as

```
class BlogPostUpdateView(generic.UpdateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = UpdateBlogForm
    success_url = "."
    template_name = "blog/dashboard_components/blog_dashboard_eidtpost.html"
```

in **updateview** i have just my **UpdateBlogForm** form, any way to edit the post related images(add/delete). Any idea how to go on?!

Answer (score 1):

I implemented using **inlineformset_factory**
`forms.py`

```
...
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory

...
ImagesFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Post,
    PostImages,
    fields=("image",),
    extra=4,
    max_num=4,
    widgets={
        "image": forms.FileInput(attrs={"class": "form-control col-md-4 col-sm-4 d-inline"}),
    },
    labels={
        "image": "",
    },
)
```

and in my `views.py` send **ImagesFormSet** with `get_context_data` as

```
from .forms import UpdateBlogForm, ImagesFormSet

...
class BlogUpdateView(generic.UpdateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = UpdateBlogForm
    success_url = "."
    template_name = "blog/dashboard_components/blog_dashboard_eidtpost.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BlogUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["images_form"] = ImagesFormSet(instance=get_object_or_404(Post, id=2))
        return context
```

and finally accessed **ImagesFormSet** as **images_form** in my template.